# Java applet can't access Firefox certificate storage

Tags: java, firefox, applet, pkcs#11

First of all, I'm relatively new to Java (and not really advanced in programming in general either), so if I missed something obvious, I apologize in advance for wasting your time.

I'm trying to create an applet that would access **Firefox**' certificate store.
What's messed up is that I would swear that this code worked when I wrote it and first tested it; Then I hibernated the PC and upon restart it didn't work anymore and ever since.

It always fails at the very beginning - at `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");` with

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS11 KeyStore not available
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I don't think there's anything that's relevant in the code, but still, here's the function that fails:

```
/* Process PDF with Firefox */
private static byte[] processFirefox() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
    ks.load(null, "myPassword".toCharArray());
    String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias,  null);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    TSAClient tsaClient = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[i];
        String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert);
        if (tsaUrl != null) {
            tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl);
            break;
        }
    }
    List<CrlClient> crlList = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();
    crlList.add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));
    return SignPDF.sign(chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, "PKCS11", CryptoStandard.CMS, "A Reason", "A Location", null, null, null, 0);
}
```

At first I thought it's because I didn't specify a provider. Then I did and nothing changed. 
What's "interesting" is that I also tried running the same applet in Chrome and it gave me the exact same error. So I'm guessing that either the applet cannot access/read Firefox' certificate store or there's something else entirely going on.
The same code, works perfectly if I substitute `PKCS11` for `"Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI"` and the password entry for `null`, so I think it's a problem specific to PKCS11/Firefox.

So there, I could really use some help with this. I've read literally every Google hit on the first couple of pages of search results, but either I'm too green for them to help or they really weren't helpful enough.

If I forgot to add any important piece of info that would help you to help me, please let me know.

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your security setup has changed?

Check out these links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/security.html

Can you access the store location using a simple FileReader?

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. I tried lowering the security settings in java cpl to the lowest setting. I tried tweaking the browser security settings. I tried a signed an an unsigned jar.

It just doesn't work. As said, it does work for type "Windows-MY" and provider "SunMSCAPI", so I'm guessing it's not about access permissions of Java.

I didn't quite understand about using a FileReader. I can access Firefox' cert8.db file, but as said, the applet fails at KeyStore.getInstance, so before I would load the KeyStore from an InputStream.

Comment: - Does it work if you just extract that piece of code and run it as a standalone Java application?
- Check out this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html
  - Is your provider config correct?
  - Maybe you want to try to dynamically create a provider?
`String configName = "/opt/bar/cfg/pkcs11.cfg"; Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);Security.addProvider(p);
`

Comment: I rechecked everything multiple times, tinkered with the config, tried dynamically creating a provider, and running everything as a stand-alone app. No cake.

I'm starting to think I imagined it working the first time.

I guess I'll just try to find an alternate way to do it. NSS/JSS seem like good ideas, even though I have to figure out how to get the user's Firefox' profile directory on the fly (which FF1.7+ doesn't allow anymore for webpages AFAIK). But that's another question altogether.

Comment: @RolandoBenjaminVazFerreira did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Oh wow this is an old one! @codenamezero - no, in the end, the whole idea was scrapped.